# VBA Filter only returning exactly half the restricted criteria items

Tags: vba, filter, outlook-2010, restrict

I am writing some VBA for Outlook, which is not something I often do. I have a strange problem with the following code:

```
    Sub Archive()
    Dim objSourceFolder As Folder
    Dim OldMessages As Outlook.Items
    Dim Allmessages As Outlook.Items
    Dim objMessage As MailItem
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim strProblemFiles As String
    Dim objTargetFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    'how old is too old? give a number in months
    '-----------------------------------------------
    Const iMonthAge = 6
    '-----------------------------------------------
    strProblemFiles = ""
    'locate the sourcefolder as the inbox
    Set objSourceFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    'locate the target folder as the only one that can work according to IT - they will make this folder consistent apparently
    Set objTargetFolder = Application.Session.Folders.GetFirst
    Set objTargetFolder = objTargetFolder.Folders("Archive")

    'There is this crappy thing on the filtering of messages where it takes a date string, not a date. So we need to calculate and then convert
    'to the format that MS lists on the MSDN site
    dtDate = DateAdd("M", -iMonthAge, Now())
    strDate = Format(dtDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM")

    'apply a filter to only show messages older than the specified date, which have been read.
    Set Allmessages = objSourceFolder.Items
    Set OldMessages = Allmessages.Restrict("[Received] <= '" & strDate & "' AND [Unread] = False")

'let the poor user know what's going on - they can bail out now if they want
If MsgBox("There are " & OldMessages.Count & " old items to archive. They will be moved from your " & objSourceFolder.Name & _
        " folder to your " & objTargetFolder.Name & " folder.", vbYesNo, "Archive Files Now?") = vbYes Then

    'go through all the messages in the big list of messages older than the specified date, moving them if possible.
    For Each objMessage In OldMessages
        If TypeName(OldMessages.GetFirst) = "MailItem" Then
                'do our shizzle
        Else
                'PRETTY MINIMAL ERROR CATCHING NEEDS IMPROVING
                'write down the name of anything that isn't mail, I guess... need to work on this
                strProblemFiles = strProblemFiles + vbCrLf + objMessage.Subject
                GoTo errorcatch
                'GoTo CarryOn
        End If
            'make a note for anyone who can look
            Debug.Print objMessage.Subject

        If objTargetFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
            If objMessage.Class = olMail Then
                    'There's nothing in errorcatch, but there will be
                    On Error GoTo errorcatch
                    'Move the item if you can
                    objMessage.Move objTargetFolder
            End If
        End If
'after an error, we jump here to go to the noxt item
CarryOn:
    Next
Else
        'if the user doesn't want to do it, we need to shut up shop and get the hell out of here
        Set objSourceFolder = Nothing
        Set OldMessages = Nothing
        Set objMessage = Nothing
        Set objTargetFolder = Nothing
        Exit Sub
End If

    'now we have done the whole thing, we can wipe down for fingerprints and exit through the window
    Set objSourceFolder = Nothing
    Set OldMessages = Nothing
    Set objMessage = Nothing
    Set objTargetFolder = Nothing

'reset the errors
On Error GoTo 0
'probably not going to be any that weren't mail items, but didn't cause a real error, but I guess we should show any we skipped.
If strProblemFiles <> "" Then MsgBox strProblemFiles

Exit Sub

'pathetic
errorcatch:
        GoTo CarryOn
End Sub

Function FileExists(FileName As String) As Boolean
    FileExists = (Dir(FileName) <> "")
End Function
```

Everything works... nearly. the first time I run the macro, it tells me that there are (e.g. 128 items ready to archive. It runs and I notice that there are still old messages in my inbox, so I run it again and it tells me there are 64 items ready for archive... then 32, 16 etc. halving the number of found messages each time. I cannot see why it would do this. Any ideas?

I should mention that this is running on Outlook 2010, using an Exchange.

Thanks for looking - all answers most appreciated!

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: Generally when looping through a set of objects it's best to first add them to a collection or other "container" before moving them or doing anything else similar. Removing objects from a collection while looping over it can cause items to "shift" in the collection, so you may end up missing some of the items altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
'...
Dim colMove As New Collection
'...
For Each objMessage In OldMessages
    If objTargetFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
        If objMessage.Class = olMail Then colMove.Add objMessage
    End If
Next

For Each objMessage In colMove
    objMessage.Move objTargetFolder
Next
'...
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks! works like a dream. I'll post the new code just for anyone reading this.

Answer (score 0):

The For Each issue is explained, and another method to move or delete items counting backwards is described here.

[For Each loop: Just deletes the very first attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469184/ive-been-trying-to-delete-the-attachments-in-outlook-after-copying-them-using-f/18469702#18469702)

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Sub Archive()
    Dim objSourceFolder As Folder
    Dim OldMessages As Outlook.Items
    Dim AllMessages As Outlook.Items
    Dim objMessage As Object
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim strProblemFiles As String
    Dim objTargetFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim colMove As New Collection
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim lngSize As Long
    Dim objAnything As Object
    Dim iMaxMBSize As Integer
    Dim boolSentItems As Boolean
    Dim catCategory As category
'    Dim boolCatExists As Boolean
'    Dim iColour As Integer

    Set objSourceFolder = Nothing
    Set OldMessages = Nothing
    Set objMessage = Nothing
    Set objTargetFolder = Nothing
    'iColour = 18
    'we are moving files, that's all, so we don't really need to worry too much about errors - if there is a problem, we can just skip the file
    'without great negative effects.
    On Error Resume Next

    'how old is too old? give a number in months
    '-----------------------------------------------
    Const iMonthAge = 6
    iMaxMBSize = 50
    '-----------------------------------------------

    'locate the sourcefolder as the inbox
    boolSentItems = (MsgBox("Your inbox will be archived." & vbCrLf & _
                            "Do you want to also archive sent items?", vbYesNo, "Archive Options") = vbYes)

    Set objSourceFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
StartAgain:
    'If you wish to assign a category to the folders rather than keep the folder structure when you archive, use this code and some other bits
    'later on, which mention the categories and the variables mentioned here.

    'Set objSourceFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
'    boolCatExists = False
'For Each catCategory In Application.Session.Categories
'    If catCategory.Name = "Archived from " & objSourceFolder.Name Then
'            boolCatExists = True
'    End If
'Next

'If boolCatExists = False Then
'        Application.Session.Categories.Add "Archived from " & objSourceFolder.Name, iColour
'End If

    'locate the target folder, which must be either in the same level as the inbox or lower
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set objTargetFolder = SearchFolders(objSourceFolder.Parent, "Archive")

'if the target folder was not found, then we need to make it, in the root directory (the same level as the inbox - this is stipulated by IT)
If objTargetFolder Is Nothing Then
        Set objTargetFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders.Add("Archive")
End If
'we are going to maintain the folder structure in the archive folder, for the inbox and sent items. This means we know exactly what to look for. If it isn't there,
'we just create it. I have used the search, rather than specifying the folders so that if the archiving is extended to more than just the inbobx and sent items, no
'change is needed.
If SearchFolders(objTargetFolder, objSourceFolder.Name) Is Nothing Then
    Set objTargetFolder = objTargetFolder.Folders.Add(objSourceFolder.Name)
Else
    Set objTargetFolder = objTargetFolder.Folders(objSourceFolder.Name)
End If

    'There is this crappy thing on the filtering of messages where it takes a date string, not a date. So we need to calculate and then convert
    'to the format that MS lists on the MSDN site
    dtDate = DateAdd("M", -iMonthAge, Now())
    strDate = Format(dtDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM")

    'apply a filter to only show messages older than the specified date, which have been read.
    Set OldMessages = objSourceFolder.Items
    Set OldMessages = OldMessages.Restrict("[Received] <= '" & strDate & "' AND [Unread] = False")

'let the poor user know what's going on - they can bail out now if they want
If OldMessages.Count > 0 Then

'    If MsgBox("There are " & OldMessages.Count & " old items in your " & objSourceFolder.Name & ". Do you want to move them from your " & objSourceFolder.Name & _
'            " folder to your " & objTargetFolder.Name & " folder.", vbYesNo, UCase(objSourceFolder.Name) + " Archive") = vbYes Then

        '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        'go through all the messages in the big list of messages older than the specified date, moving them if possible.
        'StatusForm.Show vbModeless
        For Each objMessage In OldMessages
            If TypeName(objMessage) = "MailItem" Then
                    'do our shizzle
            Else
                    'if it is not a mailitem, there may be problems moving it - add it to the list instead.
                    strProblemFiles = strProblemFiles + vbCrLf + objSourceFolder.Name + ": " + objMessage.Subject
            End If
                'make a note for anyone who can look
                Debug.Print objMessage.Subject
            'probably pointless since we are only looking in the inbox and sent items, and making the mirrors ourselves, but check the folder is correct
            If objTargetFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
                If objMessage.Class = olMail Then
                        'put the message in a nice stable collection for now - that way, we don't have to worry about the count changing etc
                        colMove.Add objMessage
                End If
            End If
        Next objMessage
        '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        'and here we have the actual move (and some optional text if you are using the categories)
        For Each objMessage In colMove
                'Move the item if you can
                'objMessage.Categories = "Archived from " & objSourceFolder.Name
                'objMessage.Save
                objMessage.Move objTargetFolder
        Next objMessage
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Else
    '        'if the user doesn't want to do it, we need to shut up shop and get the hell out of here
    '        Set objSourceFolder = Nothing
    '        Set OldMessages = Nothing
    '        Set objMessage = Nothing
    '        Set objTargetFolder = Nothing
    '        Exit Sub
    'End If
Else
        'if the count of all the old messages is not greater than 0
        MsgBox "There are no messages from more than " & iMonthAge & " months ago in your " & objTargetFolder.Name & _
        ", so nothing will be archived.", vbExclamation, "Mailbox is Clean"
End If

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'finally, loop through literally all the items in the target folders and add up the sizes to see how much we have archived in total.
For Each objAnything In objTargetFolder.Parent.Items
        lngSize = lngSize + objAnything.size
Next

'if they want to include the sent items in the archive, then change over the folder and do it all again
If boolSentItems = True Then
        boolSentItems = False
        Set objSourceFolder = SearchFolders(objSourceFolder.Parent, "Sent Items")
        'iColour = iColour + 1
        GoTo StartAgain
End If

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'once we have done all we can, let the user know about all the files that were skipped.
If strProblemFiles <> "" Then
    MsgBox "The following items were skipped, so will still be in your mailbox" & vbCrLf & strProblemFiles, vbOKOnly, "Non-Mail Items"
Else
    MsgBox "Archive complete", vbOKOnly, "Files Moved"
End If
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'the size of each file is listed in Bytes, so convert to MB to check the MB size and display, for convenience.
If lngSize / (1024 ^ 2) >= iMaxMBSize Then
        MsgBox "Your archive folder takes up " & Round(lngSize / (1024 ^ 2), 0) & "MB; it is time to call IT to ask them to clear out the files", vbOKOnly, _
        "Archive folder bigger than " & iMaxMBSize & "MB"
End If
    'now we have done the whole thing, we can wipe down for fingerprints and exit through the window
    Set objSourceFolder = Nothing
    Set OldMessages = Nothing
    Set objMessage = Nothing
    Set objTargetFolder = Nothing
    StatusForm.Hide
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

'ErrorCatch:
'If you decide to add some error checking, put it in here, although as I say, I haven't bothered (see Declaration section at top)

End Sub

Public Function SearchFolders(objTopFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, strName As String)
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

'look through all the sub folders at the level we started
For Each objFolder In objTopFolder.Folders
    'If we find the one that we are looking for, great! we can get it and get out
    If objFolder.Name = strName Then
            Set SearchFolders = objFolder
            Exit Function
    'if we haven't found our magic folder yet, we need to carry on, by looking for any sub-sub folders this is done by calling the function itself on
    'the current folder (which is by definition already one level lower than the starting location). if nothing is found, we,ll just carry on
    Else
        If objFolder.Folders.Count > 0 Then
               Call SearchFolders(objFolder, strName)
        End If
    End If
Next

'the only way to exit the loop at this point is if all the folders have been searched and the folder we were looking for was not found.
    Set SearchFolders = Nothing
End Function
```

the "StatusForm" user form that is referred to is a completely static form that just says "Archiving..." so the user is less likely to try mucking around in Outlook while the macro runs.