# Outlook VBA - Move to folder - Body text

Tags: vba, outlook

I tried to create a script which searches the body text and sender name from an incoming email and if true move the email to a subfolder.

I tried to add this code to ThisOutlookSession but it is not working.

```
Public Sub MailtoFolder(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("xTest")

    If InStr(Item.Body, "Test123") > 0 And Item.SenderName = "Jon" Then

        Item.Move myDestFolder

    End If

    Set myDestFolder = Nothing
    Set myInbox = Nothing
    Set myNameSpace = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any ideas where I made a fault?

Comment: You do realise you can create rules within outlook, which scans incoming mail, and then moves e-mails to particular sub-folders prior to the mail arriving in your main inbox?

Comment: what error are you getting, how far did the execution get to? did you put any breakpoints to debug?

Comment: I do, but you cannot add rules like "Email body text does NOT contain a specific word". Furthermore I'd like to add more conditions once the code above is working.

Comment: I don't get an error. It's running but it happens nothing.

When I set a break point Item.Body = ""

I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "Item" so far is not set.
If you wish to apply this to the currently opened e-mail, this would be e.g.

```
Set Item=Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
```

If you wish to loop through all mails in your folder, you need to do exactly that:

```
Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("xTest")
For Each mailItem in myDestFolder.Items
'  ... do your magic
Next mailItem
```

Comment: Item is set in Public Sub MailtoFolder(Item As Outlook.MailItem). As well when you move or delete items do not use a For Each. Count backwards or process item 1 repeatedly until there are no more items.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469184/ive-been-trying-to-delete-the-attachments-in-outlook-after-copying-them-using-f

Comment: You are right about going backwards when altering the index of a loop (for int i=...). Still, "Item" is *not* set just for being a seemingly passed parameter. Depends on from where you call that sub. You shouldn't alter the collection you're looping through - but that's a different question.